# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli2/Option

Tags: java, hadoop, mahout, similarity, recommendation-engine

```
Mr-Protocol:bin blossommendes$ `hadoop jar /Users/blossommendes/Desktop/Project/mahout-mrlegacy-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.similarity.item.ItemSimilarityJob -Dmapred.input.dir=/xd/hdfsImport -Dmapred.output.dir=/xd/hdfsImport/postsResults --s SIMILARITY_LOGLIKELIHOOD --booleanData`
```

after executing above command i am getting following exception .. i dont why .. please help me to solve this issue

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli2/Option
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.cli2.Option
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Please post your code. See how to write a good question in the SO help area.

Comment: Thanks for the Feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `org.apache.commons.cli2` Jar in your Classpath.